# Trying to draw dotted line with CSS

Tags: html, css, draw, css-shapes

[image]

I'm trying to draw this with CSS, I've got no solution. 
Can anyone help me with this?
Ps: I've done little searching stuff, Thank you.

Comment: what have you got so far in code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6):

You can use **CSS** `pseudo` elements here to draw dotted lines as:

```css
.border {
  border-top: 1px dotted #000000;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px 0 0 0;
  height: 4px;
}
.border::after {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.border::before {
  content: "";
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #000000;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, @vivekkupadhyay. This one almost did it.

Comment: @TelmenMunkhdalai glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

A repeating gradient can do that

```css
div {
  height: 1.5em;
  background-image: radial-gradient(grey 15%, transparent 16%), radial-gradient(grey 15%, transparent 16%);
  background-size: .5em .5em;
  background-position: 0 0, .5em .5em
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: You're right. Now that I think of it, after the initial set up, a browser might just copy the repetitive image. Initially I was thinking it would have to draw each one.

Comment: Thank you for your time, @Paulie_D. But it seems not what I am asking for. But I really appreciate your try.